# Avoid last page @page to page-break;

Tags: php, css

I have a php code like this :

```
<?php foreach ($pks as $k => $v): ?>
    <div class="content">
        //print something
    </diV>   
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I need like this. Each looping, I open a new page.

So, In css :

```
@media print {
    .content {page-break-after: always;}
    .content:last-of-type{
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }
}
```

But in last page, it creates a new page which is blank.

Please advise.

Comment: Try changing to `.content:last-child{
        page-break-after: auto;
    }` - also try keeping the `avoid`

Comment: last-of-type doesn't work with classes as far as i know. Maybe an HTML5 custom element (e.g. <page>) would allow you do do: `page:last-of-type` etc.

Comment: not working, <page></page>, also .content:last-child{ page-break-after: auto; }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and for me this code worked:

```
<style>
 .pageBreak {
   page-break-after: always;
 }
</style>

 @php
  $size = count($envelopes_paychecks);
  $pages = 1;            
 @endphp

@foreach ($envelopes_paychecks as $employee)
 <div>
  ...
 </div>
 @php
  if ( $pages < $size) {
   echo '<span class="pageBreak"></span>';
  }
  $pages++;
 @endphp
@endforeach
```